# Add the same line off text to every file

Tags: text, directory, jpeg, addition, rename

So this probably really easy only I can't find how to do this.

I have a bunch of .JPEG files I need to add something in the file name like this:

Something.JPEG need to be
Something-image.JPEG

Like I said this is probably really easy. I really hope there is a easy batch file .

Comment: StackOverflow is not a 'Code this for me'-site. Try for yourself and ask questions about a specific problem in your code.

Comment: Irfanview (www.irfanview.com) can do batch renaming like this. Fast, simple and free.